# Substract value from variable JS

Tags: javascript

I've making a game where you should sell your product.
But for some reason my function to substract that amount from the produced product, is not working, i can for some reason produce unlimited money. I've tried to check in the console what the value is after substrackting, but it is unchanged.

```
var x = document.getElementById.bind(document);
x('sell').onclick = function() {
    if (dipped_cookie < 1) {
        return false;   
    } else {
        dipped_cookie -= sell;
        console.log(dipped_cookie);
        bank += sell;
    }
```

Hope you can help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dipped_cookie, sell and bank aren't global variables, they are not defined. And when you try to add some javascript variable which is not defined, the value become NaN

Comment: I have defined the variables global.